# Best translation of "gratitude for ever"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to figure out the best translation of how to express the meaning of 'gratitude for ever.' Not necessarily grateful, but the actual emotional state of expressing gratitude; forever meaning beyond life as well. So far the best I could come up with is 'grata in saecula saeculorum.' But is this translation accurate according to what I'm trying to translate? Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by your username, you are correctly using the feminine (*grata*). Otherwise, it would be *gratus*. So I think your phrase is correct. But for the sake of shortness, I would suggest *semper grata* (which might sound familiar to Spanish speakers), or perhaps *grata in aeternum* (which might sound familiar to English speakers). I think ultimately depends on context.

I was also reading [here](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=lsn363) that an alternative could be *semper grata atque accepta*. The latter enhance the meaning in that you are grateful for something *received and accepted*. But again, depends on context.

Comment: *in perpetuum* works as well.

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that *in saecula saeculorum* seems to be a bit of a Christian/biblical expression. That does not necessarily count against it, it is just something to be kept in mind. (I was going to suggest *in sempiternum*, but it is also biblical!)